# Hide every row except the one selected

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of table rows with radio inputs:

```
<tr>
<td>
<input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="1">
</td>
</tr>
```

Q: How do hide all the rows that are not this row when it is selected?

```
$('input').filter(':radio').change(function() {
$('tr').find(not this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('input').filter(':radio').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').filter(':radio').change(function() {
    $('tr').not( $(this).closest('tr') ).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').filter(':radio').change(function() {
  $('tr, input:not(:checked)').hide();
});
```

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/BBJDx/7/)